# Filter with datum in D3js?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Is it possible to do a filtering by binding data with function datum()?

I tried to do so but the function filter() ran once and it filtered the data with all or nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.datum()` binds a single data element to a DOM element. Any filtering you do on this will affect the entire data. If you want to filter an array and bind to different elements, use `.data()` -- it doesn't really make sense to use `.filter()` with `.datum()`.